# How can I add different images instead of text inside d3.js piechart slices

Tags: svg, d3.js

Instead of the piedata variable being populated with text as it is now, I need to have the hrefs for the 5 different images. Now I have only one and it is hardcoded below rather than being pulled from the variable piedata.

I also need to have an image in the center of the circle. Ideas please

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">



<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ></script>



<head>

</head>


<body>
<style>

path {
 stroke: #fff;
 fill-rule: evenodd;
}

text {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}

</style>

<script>


var width = 550,
    height = 550,
    radius = 250
    colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(['#336699 ','#336699 ','#ACD1E9','#ACD1E9','#ACD1E9']);

 var piedata = [
    {   label: "test",
        value: 50 },
    {   label: "",
    value: 50},
    {   label: "Jonathan",
    value: 50},
    {   label: "Lorenzo",
     value: 50},
    {   label: "Hillary",
    value: 50}
  ]


 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
     .value(function(d) {
     return d.value;
  })

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .outerRadius(250)
   .innerRadius(100)


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+(width-radius)+','+(height-radius)+')')
    .selectAll('path').data(pie(piedata))
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'slice')

 var slices = d3.selectAll('g.slice')
     .append('path')
     .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
     })
       .attr('d', arc)




 var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data([0])
            imgs.enter()
            .append("svg:image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "http:/images/home-activities_09.jpg")
            .attr("x", "110")
            .attr("y", "35")
            .attr("width", "40")
            .attr("height", "40");
```

Comment: Any luck? I need the same help as well.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26692484/3442309 . Just change `.innerRadius(r - 100)` to `.innerRadius(0)` to go from donut chart to normal pie

Answer (score 3):

If all images are of constant width and height, you simply add the image URLs to your data array and dynamically set the xlink:href attribute using the data function.

```
var piedata = [
{
    label: "test",
    image: "http://placeimg.com/40/40/any",
    value: 50 
},
{   
    label: "",
    image: "http://placeimg.com/42/42/any",
    value: 50
},
{   
    label: "Jonathan",
    image: "http://placeimg.com/44/44/any",
    value: 50
},
{   
    label: "Lorenzo",
    image: "http://placeimg.com/46/46/any",
    value: 50
},
{   
    label: "Hillary",
    image: "http://placeimg.com/38/38/any",
    value: 50
}
]
....
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href",function(d) {return d.data.image;})
  .attr("width",image_width)
  .attr("height",image_height)
  .attr("x",-1*image_width/2)
  .attr("y",-1*image_height/2);
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLwr4q7s/

If, on the other hand, each image is a different size and you don't know what the width and height values are beforehand, some additional work is involved. One approach is to preload the images so that you know the width and height values once the images are loaded, and use a callback function to place them within the pie chart.

Here's an example fiddle with dynamic image dimensions: http://jsfiddle.net/LLwr4q7s/2/

Comment: Hello @OrionMelt can you please explain how to position the images further towards to the center in this example? http://jsfiddle.net/L1cmgk5n/