# Is it possible to insert an icon in the arc of a donut chart with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, donut-chart, c3.js

I have a Donut Chart with 3 categories (arcs): Facebook (50%), Twitter(30%) and Instagram(20%). Plot the chart is fairly easy, but I want to know how to insert an icon in each arc with the respective symbol of the social network (using D3 or even C3).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an image is just a case of using

```
...
.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href","myimage.png")
.attr("width", "32")
.attr("height", "32");
```

You'll also need to position (`x` and `y`). These will default to 0, so you could alternatively make use of a `translate`, something like this to find the center of the arc:

```
.attr("transform", function(d){
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
});
```

However, that just anchors the image's top-right corner to the centre of the arc, so to properly centre it you need to use the size of the image. Here's the full thing:

```
var image_width = 32;
var image_height = 32;

// add the image
arcs.append("svg:image").attr("transform", function(d){
    // Reposition so that the centre of the image (not the top left corner)
    // is in the centre of the arc
    var x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - image_width/2;
    var y = arc.centroid(d)[1] - image_height/2;
    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
})
.attr("xlink:href",function(d) { return d.data.icon;})
.attr("width", image_width)
.attr("height", image_height);
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/88t18rqg/6/

Note that I've included the image paths in the chart data. You just need to go and find proper icons!

Comment: What do you mean by "the image paths are built into the data" ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear - I just meant that the image paths are part of the data values used to create the chart. I've updated the answer now to improved the solution for better positioning of the image within the arc